# Exact stop condition for QR-algorithm

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

I'm trying to implement unshifted QR-algorithm for finding all eigenvalues of matrix. Now I'm doing QR-decomposition with Householder reflections. My program almost works but I'm confused with stop conditions. Now I'm checking if each Aij below the main diagonal is less than eps (by absolute value). But that approach does not work, because for too low epsilon loop might become infinite (some Aij below the main diagonal stops converging to zero at some moment and it's value starts to fluctuate near zero instead). So, I can't set fixed accuracy for my algorithm at the moment. Please, help.

```
bool isUpperTriangularEnough(const matrix &a)
{
    for(int i=0; i<a.getRows(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<a.getCols(); j++)
        {
            if(j < i && abs(a.getElemAt(i,j)) > eps)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

    while(!isUpperTriangularEnough(A_k))
    {
        matrix R = A_k, A_st,current_v,current_Q,Q=matrix::ident(A_k.getCols());
        for(int i=0; i<(A_k.getCols()-1); i++)
        {
            A_st = R;
            identize(A_st,i);
            current_v = getVectorV(A_st, i);
            current_Q = matrix::ident(A_st.getCols()) + (-2.0)*(current_v ^ current_v.transpose());
            R = current_Q^R;
            Q = Q^current_Q;
        }
        A_k = R ^ Q;
    }

matrix getVectorV(const matrix &A, int colIndex)
{
    matrix x = A.getColumn(colIndex);
    matrix e_i(A.getRows(), 1, false);
    e_i.setElemAt(colIndex, 0, 1.0);
    double alpha = x.get2Norm()*(-getSign(x.getElemAt(colIndex, 0)));
    matrix u = x + (-alpha*e_i);
    return u*(1.0/u.get2Norm());
}

void identize(matrix &A, int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<A.getRows(); i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<A.getCols(); j++)
        {
            if(i<n || j<n)
            {
                A.setElemAt(i,j, j==i ? 1.0 : 0.0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example: stuck in infinite loop with [[12,-51,4],[6,167,-68],[-4,24,-41]] and eps=10e-9
[image: Stuck in infinite loop]

Comment: You should be doing a reduction to Hessenberg form first. Then split the problem whenever one sub-diagonal entry is below the threshold. Stop (or do not start) processing a sub-problem if its block size is 1 or 2. Stop the algorithm if no sub-problem remains of size larger 2.

Comment: OK. P.S. Please, tell me is it possible to introduce some reliable stop condition in common case (without Hessenberg reduction)?

Comment: It remains essentially the same. All the lower sub-diagonals have to be zero according to the threshold, and the direct sub-diagonal can only contain isolated non-zero entries. From the so resulting 2x2 blocks you need to compute the eigenvalues via its characteristic equation and the quadratic solution formula. /// As extreme test case use the anti-diagonal matrix, with a 1 anti-diagonal. Its QR decomposition should leave it essentially unchanged, with the identity or some sign variation thereof as $R$ factor.

Comment: Hmm... But why the elements below the main diagonal start to fluctuate near zero without getting closer to it?

Comment: What exactly is the use of the `identize` function? (Why is the vector to be returned in the function called "get vector v" called "x" and "u", but not "v"?) The only effect that I can see is to set the elements of $x$ above the diagonal to zero. This could be done as well in the `getVectorV` function, with less effort.

Answer (score 0):

With the real-number QR algorithm one can obviously not get any complex eigenvalues as diagonal entries. They will manifest as diagonal $2\times2$ blocks. So the convergence criterion should allow for such blocks. In the end this might also result in some blocks that have real eigenvalues.

So in the test if the matrix is sufficiently upper-triangular, set a flag to false.

- for the lower sub-diagonal entries $j<i-1$ if $|a_{ij}|>\varepsilon$, then return false.
- for the direct subdiagonal, if the flag is set and $|a_{i,i-1}|>ε$, then return false. If the flag is not set and $|a_{i,i-1}|>ε$, then set the flag to true, else clear the flag to false.

```
bool isUpperTriangularEnough(const matrix &a) {
  bool flag = false;
  for(int i=0; i<a.getRows(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
      if(abs(a.getElemAt(i,j)) > eps) {
        if(j<i-1 or flag) return false;
        flag = true;
      } else {
      flag = false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

This assumes that `j<i` always, the matrix should be square so that this condition can be realized in the inner for loop.

---

To the detected error: The sign is indeed important. From a purely mathematical point of view the reduced vector $\tilde A_i$ gets reflected into $e_i$ or $-e_i$. The normal $v$ of the mirror plane is one of the two bisectors of the lines through $\tilde A_i$ and $e_i$. The bisector between them is $\frac{\tilde A_i}{\|\tilde A_i\|}\pm e_i$ or $\tilde A_i\pm\|\tilde A_i\|e_i$, then normalized to unit length. If $\tilde A_i$ is nearly dominated by its $i$th element, then the sign choice becomes critical, as one variant gives a cancellation to a near zero vector.

The stable sign choice is in conflict with the theoretically nice goal to have a positive diagonal in $R$, so some sources give the unstable choice also in the critical cancellation situation.

Comment: Now I'm working with [[12,-51,4],[6,167,-68],[-4,24,-41]] matrix. It does not have any complex eigenvalues. But my stop condition does not work anyway. P.S. I've attached the picture, so you can see what's going wrong

Comment: I do not see any such fluctuation, the lower diagonal entries fall with the factors 4.5, 10 and 2, with some sign alterations. This is exactly as predicted from the ratios of the eigenvalues, the entry $a_{ij}$ falls in absolute value with factor $\frac{|\lambda_i|}{|\lambda_j|}$. The block-criterion would leave the lower 2x2 block in a non-converged state, the exact eigenvalues can be easily computed from this block.

Comment: Using the existing QR decomposition of python numpy.linalg, I would hit the block-criterion in iteration 18 with the matrix `A = [[ 1.56136684e+02, -6.22696532e+01,  8.74609566e+01], [-4.51077429e-10, -3.41965210e+01,  1.58141345e+01], [ 9.30831954e-16,  4.89472731e-04,  1.60598369e+01]]`. Your reported iteration seems to be wrong, hinting at errors in the QR decomposition.

Comment: Maybe I shound send you my source code?

Comment: Or just add the missing computation routines `identize` and `getVectorV`. // For efficiency one should avoid to construct and compute with the reflection matrix.

Comment: I discovered the reason of my problem, actually. I used double alpha = x.get2Norm(); instead of double alpha = x.get2Norm()*(-getSign(x.getElemAt(colIndex, 0)));

Comment: P.S. I've edited my question and attached missing functions.

Comment: So, you were right, I had I mistake in QR decomposition, that caused loss of significance (according to Wikipedia), so my algorithm didn't converge

Comment: This error was even shortly in the LAPACK implementation, following the description in Numerical Recipes. // The angle bisector between two lines is indeed more stable on the shorter angle. In the QR decomposition via stable reflectors this has the strange result that the identity $I$ decomposes as $Q,R=-I,-I$.

Comment: Also noticed, that my algorithm doesn't produce valid complex eigenvalues if matrix has such eigenvalues