# Is unshifted algorithm suitable for finding conjugate and complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

I'd like to know if unshifted QR algorithm could find all kinds of eigenvalues. I notcied that it does not give correct Schur forms if matrix has complex or conjugate eigenvalues (they are calculated incorrect). Is there a mistake in my implementation or such behaviour is expected for unshifted QR-algorithm?

[image]

Source code of my program is posted here: [Exact stop condition for QR-algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352389/exact-stop-condition-for-qr-algorithm)

Comment: Could you give some test examples of where you think eigenvalues are incorrectly calculated? It is rather easy to compute the iteration sequence with numerical scripting languages like matlab or python numpy, so it should be easy to see where this goes wrong. // Multiple roots may suffer the perturbation to a small regular $m$-star of size $\mu^{1/m}$ where $\mu$ is the machine constant of the number type and $m$ the multiplicity.

Comment: Here's my source: https://pastebin.com/WCUpaVph. For example, matrix [[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,1,3]] does not converge to its Schur form.

Comment: I suspect that's something going wrong with signs again (during QR-decomposition), but I'm not sure

Comment: Your matrix $A=[1 2 3; 3 2 1; 2 1 3]$ has real eigenvalues, so it's not an example of what you're describing.  In general, the schur matrix of a real matrix with complex eigenvalues will have 2x2 blocks on the diagonal with those complex eigenvalues.

Comment: But it has conjugate real eigenvalues +-sqrt(2) and algorithm doesn't work correctly too

Comment: P.S. Problem is not in QR-decomposition, MATLAB (with built-in qr function) gives the same wrong result

Comment: The problem seems to be the translation of the bottom-right 2x2 matrix into eigenvalues. It has trace 0 and determinant -2, so that the characteristic polynomial $x^2-2$ has real roots, not a conjugate complex pair.

Comment: Hmm. So, not only conjugate complex eigenvalues produce 2x2 blocks, but real eigenvalues of opposite sign behave the same way?

Comment: Yes, groups of eigenvalues of the same absolute value can lead to stalling diagonal blocks. Only with strictly increasing magnitudes does one get convergence to zero, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4352389/exact-stop-condition-for-qr-algorithm/4352434?noredirect=1#comment9084878_4352434. This is one argument to using shifted QR, so that such clusters get separated, at least into smaller clusters.

Comment: Could you give me some literature that contains such information about QR-algorithm, please?

Comment: At the moment your explanations are much more useful than articles I've found online